# Python memory leak only in one of the identical machines

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scipy

I have two identical machines (3.6Ghz, 16GB). Python via Anaconda (Python 3.6.8, GCC 7.3.0). Copied same code in both. One machine runs the code without issue (virtual memory 8.6GB, resident 6.1GB). The 2nd one causes memory leak, quickly reaches double the size, and freezes the system. What might be the difference here?

I even copied the environment from 1st machine to the 2nd one via `conda list --explicit`. Also the 2nd machine runs another code in single-process, whereas it was running there multi-process before (not multi-process code by me, the libraries).

What should I check?

Comment: You OS installation perhaps?

Comment: Same OS. 

Further debugging reveals, my issue is related to scipy.minimize(). I was not explicitly mentioning 'L-BFGS-B', and probably having issue similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375171/scipy-optimize-minimizemethod-slsqp-memory-issues-when-outside-the-bounds. 

Though still puzzling why one machine was having the issue.